# Kafka: Producing files continuously and consuming them into files

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka and I'm writing an application which reads files from a directory continuously (Files are scp'd into this directory continuously) and produce them to one topic and on the consumer side, they have to be put into different files just like the source had. How do I go about this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you have a look into Kafka Connect? Sounds like a perfect fit for you case and you don't need to write any code. Just configure Connect.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I did look at kafka connect but wasn't sure if that is more apt or Serializer/Deserializer. Can you please provide more information on how Kafka connect can be used in this case?

Comment: Maybe you should a look into the documentation first -- no read to copy this in here... http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html Don't hesitate to ask follow up questions :)

Comment: I looked into JDBC connectors and HDFS connectors but there's not much documentation on connectors for moving files.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax So I'm able to write to a topic using file connectors. It reads from test.txt as and when new data is written to it and outputs the result to test.sink.txt. How do I do the same for entire files in a directory and writing to new files? Thank you.

Comment: You may be able to use / modify for your uses https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir

Comment: @shikhar Thank you, Shikhar. I'll look into it.